# partial sum over characters of symmetric group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

It is well known that irreducible characters of the symmetric group satisfy
orthogonality relations,

$$ \sum_{\mu \in P(n)} \chi_\mu^\lambda\chi_\mu^\omega=z_\lambda\delta_{\lambda,\omega},\quad 
\sum_{\lambda \in P(n)} \frac{1}{z_\lambda}\chi_\mu^\lambda\chi_\omega^\lambda=\delta_{\mu,\omega},$$

where $P(n)$ is the set of partitions of $n$ and $n!/z_\lambda$ is the size of a conjugacy class in that group.

I would like to know what has been proved in terms of partial or restricted such sums, i.e. quantities like
$$ \sum_{\mu \in Q} \chi_\mu^\lambda\chi_\mu^\omega \quad \text{or}\quad \sum_{\lambda \in Q} \frac{1}{z_\lambda}\chi_\mu^\lambda\chi_\omega^\lambda,$$
where $Q\subset P(n)$.

Comment: The paper by Bessenrodt and Olsson at http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1110.0818 may be relevant.